# Custom s2i in OpenShift as an Image Stream - permissions error

Tags: php, openshift, s2i

I have am using a custom Source-to-image project for build drupal images, to run on OpenShift.

The s2i project works well when run locally, from the cli.

I tried to set this up in OpenShift using instructions from https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/managing_images.html#writing-image-streams-for-s2i-builders.

**S2i Project**

The Drupal s2i project is located at https://github.com/hughestech/s2i-shepherd-drupal

**ImageStream**

My yam file looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ImageStream
metadata:
  name: drupal
  annotations:
    openshift.io/display-name: Drupal 
spec:
  tags:
    - name: '2.0' 
      annotations:
        openshift.io/display-name: Drupal Builder 
        description: >- 
          Build and run Drupal applications on CentOS 7. 
        iconClass: icon-php 
        sampleRepo: 'https://github.com/hughestech/open_social.git' 
        tags: 'builder,php, drupal' 
        version: '1.0' 
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: '172.30.1.121:5000/test/s2i-shepherd-drupal:latest'
```

However, when I run this (via the OpenShift web console > Catalog > PHP, I get the following errors:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '././phpunit.xml.dist': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././social.info.yml': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././social.install': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././social.profile': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././.gitignore': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././.travis.yml': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././README.md': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././build-social.make': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././composer.json': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././drupal-org-core.make': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '././drupal-org.make': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '././.git': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '././config': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '././libraries': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '././modules': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '././themes': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '././src': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '././tests': Permission denied
```

Clearly I need to give permissions - but how and where? Is this something I need to do in OpenShift? Does the directory that the source is being pulled into even exist in the s2i project, or is it created when the s2i process runs in OpenShift?

**Build pod error**

```
/apache2-foreground: 11: [: /var/www/html: unexpected operator
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.128.1.64. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Sep 12 13:07:05.474838 2017] [core:emerg] [pid 1] (13)Permission denied: AH00023: Couldn't create the rewrite-map mutex (file /var/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.1)
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: Can you provide a URL to the repository containing source code used to make the S2I builder. It appears that it isn't setting up file system permissions correctly. If can see how it is implemented can better guide you.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question to contain this information Thanks Graham.

Comment: From what I can tell, that S2I builder as written can only produce images using the ``s2i`` command line tool that can be run outside of OpenShift using ``docker run``. It has not had the work done on it to allow it to work when assigned an ID to run as will occur by default under OpenShift. The only way to have the images work in OpenShift is if security is relaxes to allow the image to be run as anyuid. Running images as anyuid is not allowed in OpenShift Online if you are using that.

Comment: Add this script to your image. https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-base-container/blob/master/core/root/usr/bin/fix-permissions Have ``WORKDIR`` be ``/var/www`` and that Apache/PHP is using it. Run ``chown -R 1001:0 /var/www``. The group must be ``0``. And use that ``fix-permissions`` script to fix up permissions on ``/var/www``, initially, and then after any files after have been added into ``/var/www``.

Comment: BTW, you can check it will work if building from command line using ``s2i``, by running as ``docker run -u 10000001 imagename``. That will force it to be uid different to the S2I image as would occur under OpenShift.

Comment: Ok, that all makes sense. One question - where do I place the `fix-permissions` script?

Comment: Where ever you want. Just ensure it is executable. In the S2I builders that come with OpenShift they stick it in ``/usr/bin`` so is in the ``PATH``.

Comment: I have made the changes you advice, but am still getting the same permission errors. I'm calling `fix-permissions ./` at the end of the `assemble`.

Comment: You need to run in on ``/var/www`` in the ``Dockerfile`` as well ``RUN chown -R 1001:0 /var/www && fix-permissions /var/www``.

Comment: Still getting the same permissions error unfortunately

Comment: Which of the errors? FWIW. It would probably have been better to derive your custom image from the OpenShift PHP S2I builder. Any reason you didn't do that?

Comment: the errors are exactly the same as in the original question - none of the changes have made any difference. The reason for going with this s2i was that it installs the various drupal tools.